# Rails One-to-many association Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_may :friends
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Tables:**

[image: tables image]

**To Query:**

`users` which both has:

```
friends.name = "Lily" 
# and 
friends.name = "Steven"
```

I want by **Model Where Query** like:

```
User.joins(xxx).where(xxx)
```

Is there any way to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
User.joins(:friends).where("friends.name = 'Lily' OR friends.name = 'Steven'")
```

will do what you are looking for

Comment: No, if there is a record under friends 10th: 11  3   Lily, the result will be incorrect.

Comment: I didn't get you at all. What exactly do you mean by "record under friends 10th: 11 3 Lily, the result will be incorrect."

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id, users.name 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN friends ON users.id = friends.user_id 
WHERE friends.name IN ('Lily', 'Steven') 
GROUP BY users.id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

ActiveRecord Query

```
names = ['Lily', 'Steven']

User.select('users.id, users.name').joins(:friends).where(friends: { name: names }).group('users.id').having("COUNT(*) = #{names.count}")
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45feb5/8/0)

The query above will return you only the users who are friends with `"Lily"` and `"Steven"`